# Dissimilar table cell heights in a given row

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I want to mimic this in my Word 2007:

[image]

Using table with thick border as well as having border colour as same as page colour I was able (partially) to get the same effect as above:

[image]

However in the original picture how can someone attain a dissimilar cell height in a particular row of a table

Answer (score 0):

You can make cells in the same row appear to vary in height by combining cells in adjacent rows.

Highlight two or more cells and click "Merge and center" on the home tab as in the screenshot below...
[image]

...and the merged cells will end up looking like this
[image]

To center the cell contents vertically, click the button in the Alignment section of the Home tab as shown below.

[image]

You can copy the table in Excel and paste it into Word You can merge cells in MS Word using the Merge Cells command on the Table Tools -> Layout tab or just copy and paste from Excel to Word. The table, copied from Excel, will appear in Word as below.

[image]

Comment: But you see 'D' isn't centered in the merged cell, although it can be made to wrap-center but still the padding of filled red isn't same at four sides EQUALLY

Comment: @nightcrawler: There is a button on the home tab that will allow you to center the cell contents vertically. I've added a screenshot to my original answer.